# iOS CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost local Port

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp

I am trying to connect an iOS device with a server trough TCP. I am currently using the function *CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost*. My problem is that i want to set the local port that the iOS device needs to use. Is there anyone who has experience with this and could tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

I am now using the [cocoaasyncsocket library](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/).
Connecting with a host using the function *connectToAddress: viaInterfaceAddress: withTimeout: error:* gave me the possibility to define my local port.

Comment: This URL is not working can you put some sample code.

Comment: I think it's the following project: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

I cannot give you any sample code because I don't have access to the source anymore.